# How can I remove hoa from my Laravel project with Composer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I happened to install `hoa` for running the fourstream websocket package for my Laravel project. But after installing I am getting

> "Hoa main file (`Core.php`) must be included once"

for every Composer command I run. How can I undo this and remove `hoa` completely from my project?

I can't do `composer update` as it will update my Laravel 5.1 version to Laravel 5.2.

Comment: I hope I understand the question, can you just remove it from the composer.json file? Then delete the folder for it in vendor?

Comment: Remove from composer.json then run composer update

Comment: @MikeRockett no `composer update` will update all of his other dependencies too, what he wrote he doesn't want to.

Comment: @Peh - No, `composer update` will only update to 5.2 if `composer.json` points to `laravel/framework 5.2.*`.

Comment: @MikeRockett yes you are right for the Laravel Framework itself but all other dependencies would still update if you run composer update. Thats why you should always use composer remove because it removes only one package without touching the other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Composer's `remove` command from command line

```
php composer.phar remove vendor/package
```

Where `vendor/package` must be changed to the package name you want to be removed e.g. `hoa/core`.

Comment: I think i tried this.But didn't worked. It showed there are no packages named 'hoa/core'. But the package was present in the vendor folder. 

Btw I managed to fix this by using a backup.

Comment: Maybe the package hoa/core was installed by another package. But you would have to look up the correct name in your composer.json. Then the remove command should work.